# How can I increase the performance of this FormView / SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource, formview

I have a simple asp FormView on my page, it's working fine and everything, but I noticed the page is somewhat slow to load up (2-3 seconds), when there's really no reason for it, it's such a simple page.

The problem is that the FormView is using a SqlDataSource, which is using a 'heavy' select statement, basically grabbing all the fields and all rows of a profile table (name, address, phone, etc.).  I'm assuming the FormView needs to get all the records so the Paging works correctly, but is there a way to code it or an attribute I can use so it doesn't grab every row and column but just all the columns of the current NameId?

asp:

```
<asp:FormView ... DataSourceId="sdsNames" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="NameId">
   <EditItemTemplate>....</EditItemTemplate>
   <InsertItemTemplate>...</InsertItemTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'.../> 
       ...
   </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:FormView>
 <SqlDataSource ID="sdsNames" ... SelectCommand="SELECT * from tblNames">
```

I tried changing the SelectCommand to

```
SELECT * from tblNames where NameId=1
```

since the initial page should show the first entry.  But then I lose the pagination, basically no way to view the next record.

What the Page looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a lot you can do to improve performance here.  You're correct, the SqlDataSource does slow things down because it retrieves all of the rows from your table.

There are a couple of different approaches that come to my mind:

**Remove fields from your query.**
This is the simplest solution, though it might not apply to your situation.  If there are fields you don't need to display / modify, remove them.  So, rather than `SELECT * FROM...`, you have `SELECT LName, FName, Mname FROM...`

You're still getting every row, but at least there is less data in each row.

**You could switch to the ObjectDataSource control.**
I haven't used this control much, [but MSDN says that it performs a little better](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227443%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), because it doesn't always have to retrieve every row:

> Some data sources, such as the ObjectDataSource control, offer more
>   advanced paging capabilities. In these cases the FormView control
>   takes advantage of the data source's more advanced capabilities to
>   gain better performance and flexibility while paging. The number of
>   rows requested may vary depending on whether the data source supports
>   retrieving the total row count.

**You could move away from the datasource controls.**
This probably involves more complexity than what you're looking for, but it is the most flexible approach.  You can retrieve just the columns and rows you want.  You can create a PagerTemplate, and set the values when the FormView is databound.  You would have to handle the PageIndexChanging and PageIndexChanged events to change the paging values yourself.

Comment: Awesome answer.  I kind of thought there was no simple solution, but thanks for offering 3 great other options.

Comment: You're very welcome, @russds.  I'm glad I could at least help a little =)